# postgresql: temporary json variable possible?

Tags: postgresql

How can I create a temporary / very shortlived json object that I can reference (for building checks in RLS policies)? The policies will be invoked later with the "real" json object as a session variable, I just won't have access to the values till runtime and I have no control over this.

I was thinking of SET LOCAL, but it doesn't look like you can use json types with it? Can I *fake* a json type? eg I tried:

```sql
SET LOCAL myjson '{"foo":123, "color":red}';
SELECT myjson ->> 'foo';
```

but I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'{"foo":123, "color":red}'"
LINE 1: SET LOCAL myjson '{"foo":123, "color":red}';
                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 18
```

Comment: There is nothing that keeps the user from setting the placeholder parameter to something else and subvert RLS that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on whether you need to have the exact `SELECT myjson ->> 'foo';` syntax, there are several options.  I'm only going to cover a few:

If you need `SELECT myjson ->> 'foo';`, the closest I can think of is to create a function that returns json:

```
edb=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myjson() RETURNS json AS $$ BEGIN RETURN '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}'::json; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

edb=# SELECT myjson ->> 'foo';
 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

If you can afford to use a CTE, you could do it this way:

```
edb=# WITH x AS (SELECT '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}'::json AS myjson)
SELECT myjson ->> 'foo' FROM x;
 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

You could even put `myjson` into a temporary table:

```
edb=# SELECT '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}'::json AS myjson INTO TEMPORARY TABLE temptable;
SELECT 1
edb=# SELECT myjson->>'foo' FROM temptable;
 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

If you want to use `SET LOCAL`, you'll encounter a few gotchas:

1. [Needs to be in a transaction block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) (i.e., `BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK`)
2. [Needs to be prefixed with a namespace of sorts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) (any name is fine)
3. You can't just `SELECT` it as though it were a variable floating in your session, you'll need to use `current_setting()`
4. You'll need to cast it after you retrieve it with `current_setting()` (in other words, you have to store it as text, not as json)

A working example would be something like this:

```
edb=# SET LOCAL myjson = '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}';
WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "myjson"
edb=# SET LOCAL myparam.myjson = '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}';
WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks
SET
edb=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
edb=# SET LOCAL myparam.myjson = '{"foo":"123", "color":"red"}';
SET
edb=# SELECT current_setting('myparam.myjson');
       current_setting        
------------------------------
 {"foo":"123", "color":"red"}
(1 row)

edb=# SELECT current_setting('myparam.myjson')::json ->> 'foo';
 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

If you want to use `SET` but don't want to use `BEGIN/COMMIT` blocks, try using `SET SESSION` (or just plain `SET`) instead.  You'll still need to put it into a namespace (i.e., `foo.myjson`) and use `current_setting(foo.myjson)` to extract it.

Comment: for some reason I completely missed this answer and I had forgotten about what I had needed this for. Thanks for the detailed response esp points 1 to 4!